# Autodesk Forge - Best training for transitioning from desktop .Net coding

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I have background in Inventor/Revit API development only, and need to learn enough JS to be able to work comfortably with the Forge APIs. I'll be booking myself into a JS training course to learn general skills, but what topics/modules must I definitely cover to have a solid foundation for Forge API development. I'll be working with BOM data, viewers and possibly web configurators.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

We're a .Net shop that recently implemented the Forge Viewer for a client with Inventor Files.  We built our service on top of Azure Functions and utilized as much .Net C# code as possible, as it is where we have the most experience and comfortability.  The provided .Net SDK is very helpful: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autodesk.Forge/.

The only API that you can't do entirely in .Net is the Viewer API.  However, to get started I was able to use boilerplate code from the provided examples and get the models loading.  From there I had our web developers get involved to handle the more extensive javascript programming for me.

Feel free to bounce any questions you may have off of me.  We've just finished going down this road and it is very rewarding, but somewhat challenging at times for us .Net developers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, very helpful. I'm trying to put together an agenda of topics I need some understanding of in order to approach the boilerplate samples and Autodesk blogs with some degree of understanding (as the Autodesk blogs generally assume they are talking to 'web-aware' developers, which I am not). It appears I need to learn basic Javascript, JSON, REST, and how to use Azure functions? So I can find a trainer who can cover those topics for beginners and I'll have a good start? Any other advice welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You need the JavaScript, as you already know. Take some time to improve [security](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/expanding-net-desktop-apps-cloud-security) and [OAuth authentication workflow](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/expanding-net-desktop-apps-cloud-oauth). This [sample](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/expanding-net-desktop-apps-cloud-sample-code) includes most of it.

In most cases, you'll need a hybrid desktop app that can connect to the cloud, the image below (from the blog post) shows a generic approach for the architecture using Autodesk Forge (or any other cloud APIs).

[image]

Comment: Hi Augusto, thanks for the reply, however your blogs assume a basic understanding about web programming that I don't possess. I need training on the core principles before I'll understand your blogs I think.

Comment: search for ASP.NET and WebApi, you may also look for jQuery. Look for some concepts behind Rest and JSON

Comment: Thanks Augusto - that gets me pointed in the right direction!